# Java 8 - how to copy a property value from one list to another?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have two `List`s, for example:

```
List<Foo> list1 = Lists.newArrayList(new Foo(...),...);
List<Bar> list2 = Lists.newArrayList(new Bar(...),...);
```

In `Bar` there is a property, `fooId`. Suppose `list1.size() == list2.size()`.
I want to set `fooId`s of the `Bar` instances in order.

I tried below code:

```
int index = 0;
list2.forEach(b -> b.fooId = list1.get(index++).getId());
```

but compilation failed

> Local variable index defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Does Java 8 have some convenient manner to process this?

Answer (score 5):

You can't modify the `index` variable from inside the lambda expression.

You can iterate over the indices using an `IntStream` (though that's not much of an improvement compared to a simple for loop) :

```
IntStream.range(0,list1.size())
         .forEach(i -> list2.get(i).setFooId(list1.get(i).getId()));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
IntStream.range(0, list1.size())
         .forEach(i -> list2.get(i).fooId = list1.get(i).getId());
```

but do note that this is not good functional code. You would be better to write an explicit `for` loop and not use Stream.

The code in your question doesn't work because you can't reference a variable inside a lambda expression that isn't final (or effectively final).

If you don't mind about `list1` after this operation and its element can be removed, you could also use this:

```
list2.forEach(bar -> bar.fooId = list1.remove(0).getId());
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no zip operation in Java 8 streams API. But you can use [protonpack](https://github.com/poetix/protonpack) library.

```
List<Bar> upd = StreamUtils.zip(list1.stream(), list2.stream(), (foo, bar) -> {
  bar.setId(foo.getId());
  return bar;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I also want to add that using mutable data objects is an imperative style. In functional style it is preferable to use immutable data and return new objects instead if you need to change anything.

Answer (score 2):

Using my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library you can reduce the boilerplate:

```
EntryStream.zip(list1, list2).forKeyValue((foo, bar) -> bar.fooId = foo.getId());
```

[`EntryStream.zip`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/EntryStream.html#zip-java.util.List-java.util.List-) creates a stream of `Map.Entry<Foo, Bar>` for each corresponding pair of `list1` and `list2`. The [`forKeyValue`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/EntryStream.html#forKeyValue-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) method accepts `BiConsumer` (it's a syntactic sugar for `forEach`). Internally it's close to @Eran solution.